# eslint Trailing spaces not allowed detection and removal of the trailing spaces?

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint

I am trying eslint.  It reports the "Trailing spaces not allowed" problem.  I was wondering since it can detect the problem, is there an automatic way to fix the problem by removing them automatically?

Comment: Most text editors provide regular expression global replace. Replace `\s+$` with the empty string to remove trailing spaces.

Comment: Using `eslint` there is no way to automatically fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Autofixing is on a road map for version 2.0.0. Currently there is no way to have ESLint auto fix reported errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check error lines after building app, remove extra spaces, build app and run again, I hope it will work, I have tried and its working on my side.